# Identifying column with the first value in the row based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe where I want to identify the column for each row which has the first value corresponding to a condition. In this case below I want to create a new column which identifies the first value in each row which is less than or equal to 1 and gives me the corresponding column name.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1.5,2,4,0.5], 'B' : [2,1,3,0.25], 'C': [3,1,1,1], 'D': [2,2,3,1]})
df
    A    B      C   D
0   1.5  2.00   3   2
1   2.0  1.00   1   2
2   4.0  3.00   1   3
3   0.5  0.25   1   1
```

I can create a mask to check for the condition.

```
temp = df<=1
temp
    A       B       C       D
0   False   False   False   False
1   False   True    True    False
2   False   False   True    False
3   True    True    True    True
```

I can then use the following to determine the columns.

```
df['New_col'] = temp.idxmax(axis = 1)
df
    A    B      C   D   New_col
0   1.5  2.00   3   2   A
1   2.0  1.00   1   2   B
2   4.0  3.00   1   3   C
3   0.5  0.25   1   1   A
```

The code identifies the columns in New_col correctly except for row 0 as all of the values in row 0 are greater than 1.
How can I get NaN instead of A for row 0 in the New_col?

Below is the output desired.

```
    A    B      C   D   New_col
0   1.5  2.00   3   2   NaN
1   2.0  1.00   1   2   B
2   4.0  3.00   1   3   C
3   0.5  0.25   1   1   A
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `any(1)` to check if there is a `True` on the rows, and `where` to mask:

```
df['New_col'] = temp.idxmax(axis = 1).where(temp.any(1))
```

Output:

```
     A     B  C  D New_col
0  1.5  2.00  3  2     NaN
1  2.0  1.00  1  2       B
2  4.0  3.00  1  3       C
3  0.5  0.25  1  1       A
```